# Passing range as function(arguments)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pass a range as a parameter in a function so that I can select and clear it.

However, I keep getting an Application defined/object defined error.

If I do this in my clearData method where I just do `range("m3").select` instead of `range(test).select` it works.

What am i doing wrong?

```
Sub CopyData()
    Call ClearData("Detailed Report", Sheets("Detailed Report").range("M3"))
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    range("A2").Select
    range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Detailed Report").Select
    range("M3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Sub ClearData(sheetName As String, range As range)
    Sheets(sheetName).Select
    Dim deletrange As range
    Set deletrange = range
    range(deletrange).Select
    deletrange(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    deletrange(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Range is an object and you are using same variable I think that's confusing try using different variable name also there is a lot select statements which is not the right way to do what you are doing. You can simply define the range and clear it's contents without selecting. Also post your code in the question not the picture so that it's easy for editing.

Comment: Hi @newguy, i was editing to add my code. apologies about it.

Comment: Just FYI, for your code, since deletRange is a range object, not an address, you would use `deletrange.Select` and not `range(deletrange).Select`

Comment: @Adrian Lee Xinhan  have you checked into the answeres you got below ? any feebdack ?

Comment: Hi @ShaiRado didnt work so far. Seems to be clearing my Detailed report whole worksheet instead of M3 onwards. I am trying not to clear the range before m3 becasuse there are some formulas in my cell.  Am trying to test more and will provide more an update!

Comment: @AdrianLeeXinhan  you want range(M3) all the way down and to the right , correct ?

Comment: Hi all i realised why. 

So my detailed report sheet is formatted as an entire table. What happens when I use currentRegion.clearcontents, it clears my entire detailed report sheet. 

To give some context, In my detailed report sheet, I actually have formulas stored in columns before m3 (i.e A3 to M3). Hence if you use currentRegion.clearcontents, it cleared my entire excel sheet including the formulas. 

Therefore using the Rng.Resize(Rng.End(xlDown).Row, Rng.End(xlToRight).Column).ClearContents cleared the data from row M3 onwards but preserved the formulas from A3 to m3.

Comment: @AdrianLeeXinhan  so is your issue resolved ? Using the first option in my answer ?

Comment: @ShaiRado  yupps resolved! used the first option! :) Thank you very much for your help! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not define variables with names like `range`, since `Range` is an Excel saved word.

Also, there's no need to `Select` and `Selection` , instead use fully qualified Ranges and worksheets.

**Note**: keep in mind that using `End(xlDown)` and`End(xlToRight)` to get the last row and column is not the safest way. If you want to use the continuous  range with "M3", then use `Range("M3").CurrentRegion`.

If you want to get the entire sheet's range, including empty rows and columns in the middle, then use:

To get the Last row use:

```
Sheets("Detailed Report").Cells(Sheets("Detailed Report").Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
```

To get the Last column use:

```
Sheets("Detailed Report").Cells(3, Sheets("Detailed Report").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).columnn
```

**Code**

```
Sub CopyData()    
    ClearData "Detailed Report", Sheets("Detailed Report").Range("M3")        
    ' Copy >> Paste in 1 line (without Selecting)
    Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").Resize(Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row, Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column).Copy _
    Sheets("Detailed Report").Range("M3")          
End Sub

'=====================================================================

Sub ClearData(sheetName As String, Rng As Range)
    ' the code line below uses your original method, less recommended
    Rng.Resize(Rng.End(xlDown).Row, Rng.End(xlToRight).Column).ClearContents        

    ' better of using the code line below:
    Rng.CurrentRegion.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: gentle note that if you are going to edit your code to incorporate part of my answer (CurrentRegion) then an attribution would be nice.

Comment: @brettdj I'm just not a fast typer like you bret, and  I still need to re-edit here, cause My Internet explorer at work doesn't have spelling correction (so i got to copy this to outlook to correct grammer and spelling mistakes) . But  I will +1 (don't want any bad blood)

Comment: No bad blood Shai, my note was meant to be polite not edgy. Thx for the upvote (returned in kind) :)

Comment: @brettdj thanks bret, you can never know here, there is a lot of ego among programmers here :)

Comment: there certainly is. Some thin skins as well .... liking your contributions, keep up the good work.

Comment: @brettdj let me know when you want to use my services :)

Answer (score 1):

Passing the sheet is overkill, you can pass just the range.

If you were to pass the sheet, pass it as an object, not a sheet name.

`CurrentRegion` also will suffice for what you want

```
Sub Better()
Dim rng1 As range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Sheets("Detailed Report").[m3]
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then Call ClearData(rng1)
End Sub
```

*clear code*

```
Sub ClearData(rng1 As range)
rng1.CurrentRegion.ClearContents
End Sub
```